# HTML5 and Javascript to play videos only when visible

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I am interested in setting up an HTML page with multiple video clips such that each video clip plays only while visible and then pauses when out of view.

I have found [this great example](http://jsbin.com/ocupor/1/edit) of how this can be implemented with one clip, but I have been unable to modify the code to work with multiple clips.  Perhaps I need to convert this code into a function for easy re-usability?

Here is what I have so far (JS Bin linked above modified for 2 clips instead of one).

This code seems to work for only one of the two clips.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <!--   Created using jsbin.com   Source can be edited via http://jsbin.com/ocupor/1/edit
    -->
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>JS Bin</title>
        <style>
            #right {
                position: absolute;
                top: 2000px;
            }
            #video1 {
                position: absolute;
                left: 2000px;
                top: 2000px;
            }
            #video2 {
                position: absolute;
                left: 2000px;
                top: 3000px;
            }

        </style>

        <style id="jsbin-css">
        </style>
    </head>
    #
    <body style="width: 4000px; height: 4000px;">
        <div id="info"></div>
        <div id="down">
            scroll down please...
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            scroll right please...
        </div>
        <video id="video1">
            <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4"/>

        </video>
        <script>
            var video = document.getElementById('video1'), fraction = 0.8;

            function checkScroll() {
                var x = video.offsetLeft, y = video.offsetTop, w = video.offsetWidth, h = video.offsetHeight, r = x + w, //right
                b = y + h, //bottom
                visibleX, visibleY, visible;

                visibleX = Math.max(0, Math.min(w, window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth - x, r - window.pageXOffset));
                visibleY = Math.max(0, Math.min(h, window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - y, b - window.pageYOffset));

                visible = visibleX * visibleY / (w * h);

                if (visible > fraction) {
                    video.play();
                } else {
                    video.pause();
                }
            }

            checkScroll();
            window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll, false);
            window.addEventListener('resize', checkScroll, false);
        </script>

        <video id="video2">
            <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4"/>

        </video>
        <script>
            var video = document.getElementById('video2'), fraction = 0.8;

            function checkScroll() {
                var x = video.offsetLeft, y = video.offsetTop, w = video.offsetWidth, h = video.offsetHeight, r = x + w, //right
                b = y + h, //bottom
                visibleX, visibleY, visible;

                visibleX = Math.max(0, Math.min(w, window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth - x, r - window.pageXOffset));
                visibleY = Math.max(0, Math.min(h, window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - y, b - window.pageYOffset));

                visible = visibleX * visibleY / (w * h);

                if (visible > fraction) {
                    video.play();
                } else {
                    video.pause();
                }
            } checkScroll();
            window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll, false);
            window.addEventListener('resize', checkScroll, false);

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using the [isInViewport](https://github.com/zeusdeux/isInViewport) plugin and [jQuery](http://jquery.com), here's my code for the task

```
$('video').each(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":in-viewport")) {
        $(this)[0].play();
    } else {
        $(this)[0].pause();
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm trying to get this code to work for me, it is much simpler. I'm having trouble, though.  Since I have switch over to a wordpress-based site, my videos follow the following example format: `class="wp-video-shortcode" id="video-1115-1"`

Comment: Any way to modify the [0] to work with this is `video-XXXX-X` formatting?

Comment: Can we apply to Vimeo stating that it run under iframe? How to?

Comment: Downvoted because OP did not specify jQuery tag. It is expected, the question is for vanilla javascript.

Comment: It does not work. I just get "Script error". https://jsfiddle.net/6agbqjsL/

Comment: @Black You need to choose "jQuery" from the library dropdown

Comment: @KalleH.Väravas this was not the case in 2014 when this answer was posted and also, these esoteric rules only discourage contributions.

Comment: I get the error Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: in-viewport

Answer (score 27):

OK, I think, it must be something like this:

```
var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video");

function checkScroll() {
    var fraction = 0.8; // Play when 80% of the player is visible.

    for(var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {

        var video = videos[i];

        var x = video.offsetLeft, y = video.offsetTop, w = video.offsetWidth, h = video.offsetHeight, r = x + w, //right
            b = y + h, //bottom
            visibleX, visibleY, visible;

            visibleX = Math.max(0, Math.min(w, window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth - x, r - window.pageXOffset));
            visibleY = Math.max(0, Math.min(h, window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - y, b - window.pageYOffset));

            visible = visibleX * visibleY / (w * h);

            if (visible > fraction) {
                video.play();
            } else {
                video.pause();
            }

    }

}

window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', checkScroll, false);
```

Comment: I was getting a "fraction not defined" ReferenceError, but works perfectly once I added back the definition: 

fraction = 0.8;

Comment: Yep, fraction just needs to be defined somewhere- great answer though :)

Comment: That does not work for me but is useful as a reference.

Answer (score 23):

None of the above seemed to work for me, but I finally found a way: you'll need [the `visible` plugin](https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible), and this little piece of code right here:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('video').each(function() {
        if ($(this).visible(true)) {
            $(this)[0].play();
        } else {
            $(this)[0].pause();
        }
    })
});
```

This will allow any video to play only when it gets into viewport. By replacing `visible( true )` by `visible()`
, you can set it to play only when the entire video DOM element is in viewport.

Comment: If you guys don't want to use a plugin, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/how-to-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling#answer-23361984) answer out.

Answer (score 9):

Y'all need to get with the times and use IntersectionObserver (and the appropriate polyfill or babeifyl). This script will play/pause all videos on a page when they scroll in/out of view. Boom.

```
<script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=IntersectionObserver%2CIntersectionObserverEntry"></script> 
<script>
    let video = document.querySelector('video');
    let isPaused = false;
    let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => { 
        entries.forEach(entry => {
        if(entry.intersectionRatio!=1  && !video.paused){
            video.pause();
            isPaused = true;
        }
        else if(isPaused) {
            video.play(); 
            isPaused=false}
        });
    }, {threshold: 1});
    observer.observe(video);
</script>
```

[source](https://css-tricks.com/a-few-functional-uses-for-intersection-observer-to-know-when-an-element-is-in-view/)

Comment: kind of curious what the `isPaused` flag is doing. Is it some kind of performance flag, or is required for the effect to work?

Comment: it looks like it should be stripped out.

Comment: yes, could be as simple as `if (entry.intersectionRatio !== 1) video.pause() else video.play()`

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/a-few-functional-uses-for-intersection-observer-to-know-when-an-element-is-in-view/ - looking back, it's to know if the video was autopaused,

Answer (score 7):

Need to check if the video is visible during the scrolling.

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('video').each(function(){
        if ($(this).is(":in-viewport")) {
            $(this)[0].play();
        } else {
            $(this)[0].pause();
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery, [isInViewport](https://github.com/zeusdeux/isInViewport), and Coffeescript, the complete solution for me looked like this:

```
$(window).scroll ->
  $('video:in-viewport').each -> $(@)[0].play()
  $('video:not(:in-viewport)').each -> $(@)[0].pause()
```

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but just wanted to add my two cents, I initially started with the jQuery code above, but ran into some issues with the implementation.  This solution should work with multiple videos, and also prevents a problem where the user pauses a video and tries to scroll away and it just starts again:

```
<script>
    var videoList = [];
    var scrollPauseList = [];
    var clickedPauseList = [];
</script>
<script>    
    var myScrollFunc = function() {

        $(".video-js").each(function(){ 

            var inView = $(this).is(":in-viewport");
            var isPaused = $(this)[0].player.paused();
            var playerIdx = videoList.indexOf(this.id);
            var scrollPaused = scrollPauseList[playerIdx];
            var clickPaused = clickedPauseList[playerIdx];

            if (inView) {                       
                var hasEnded = $(this)[0].player.ended();
                var curTime = $(this)[0].player.currentTime();
                var hasStarted = curTime > 0;
                if(hasStarted && !hasEnded && !clickPaused)
                {
                    scrollPauseList[playerIdx] = false;
                    $(this)[0].player.play();
                }
            } else if(!isPaused) {                      
                scrollPauseList[playerIdx] = true;
                $(this)[0].player.pause();
            }
        });
    };      

    $(window).scroll(myScrollFunc);     
</script>   

<video  
  class="video-js" controls></video>

<script>
$(".video-js").each(function(){ 
        videoList[videoList.length] = this.id;
        scrollPauseList[scrollPauseList.length] = false;
        clickedPauseList[scrollPauseList.length] = false;
    }); 

for(var i = 0; i < videoList.length; i++)
{
    var playerID = videoList[i];
    var player = videojs(playerID);

    player.on('pause', function() {
        var pID = videoList.indexOf(this.id());

        if(!scrollPauseList[pID])
        {
            clickedPauseList[pID] = true;
            scrollPauseList[pID] = false;
        }
        else
        {
            clickedPauseList[pID] = false;
            scrollPauseList[pID] = false;
        }
    });
}       
</script>
```

I've scrubbed some stuff, and i'm using video-js, so you may need to modify it a bit to get your implementation to work.

Answer (score 2):

Tried many solutions, the only one partially working is the one posted below. The problem is that having 3 videos on the page, the second one and the third one are basically controlled by the first one.

So they start playing when the page is loaded (while they are supposed to play when in viewport) and they get paused when the first get paused, any suggestion on having this working with multiple videos?

Tried using `getElementById` but didn't work, tried also jquery plugins but no good results.

Here you have the www page where you can see what happen and all source code of course.

http://185.197.128.183/~monompro/

```js
window.onload = function() {

    var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video"),
        fraction = 0.8;

    function checkScroll() {

        for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {

            var video = videos[i];

            var x = video.offsetLeft,
                y = video.offsetTop,
                w = video.offsetWidth,
                h = video.offsetHeight,
                r = x + w, //right
                b = y + h, //bottom
                visibleX, visibleY, visible;

            visibleX = Math.max(0, Math.min(w, window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth - x, r - window.pageXOffset));
            visibleY = Math.max(0, Math.min(h, window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - y, b - window.pageYOffset));

            visible = visibleX * visibleY / (w * h);

            if (visible > fraction) {
                video.play();
            } else {
                video.pause();
            }

        }

    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll, false);
    window.addEventListener('resize', checkScroll, false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7557433/11950764), the `offsetTop`/`offsetLeft`/etc. approaches are slower and more error prone than the newer `getBoundingClientRect` approach. Here's some working code to play any videos that are even partially visible in the viewport:

```js
function playVisibleVideos() {
  document.querySelectorAll("video").forEach(video => elementIsVisible(video) ? video.play() : video.pause());
}

function elementIsVisible(el) {
  let rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (rect.bottom >= 0 && rect.right >= 0 && rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && rect.left <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth));
}

let playVisibleVideosTimeout;
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  clearTimeout(playVisibleVideosTimeout);
  playVisibleVideosTimeout = setTimeout(playVisibleVideos, 100);
}, {passive: true});

window.addEventListener("resize", playVisibleVideos);
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", playVisibleVideos);
```

The `setTimeout` stuff ensures that the `playVisibleVideos()` function isn't called any more often than once every 100ms as the user scrolls (so it doesn't cause lag). The `{passive: true}` ensures the scroll handler function doesn't "block" scrolling (which can cause scroll lag).

Note that it seems like [@Tristanisginger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58914563/11950764) using the more modern `IntersectionObserver` approach may be a better choice than this one for most people.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else runs into this question, I was unable to use Saike's solution on my WordPress site because of the way the videos were auto embedded (MediaElement player).  However, qwazix's solution worked with some modification.  Here is the jQuery code that works with the [IsInView plugin](https://github.com/zeusdeux/isInViewport).  Here are my include scripts (placed at the end of `footer.php` in my theme folder).

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/isInViewport.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/scrollview.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And the jQuery code (modify 400 to your tolerance liking)

```
  $(function() {
      $(window).scroll(function() {
          $('.wp-video-shortcode').each(function() {
              var str = $(this).attr('id');
              var arr = str.split('_');
              typecheck = arr[0];
              if ($(this).is(":in-viewport( 400 )") && typecheck == "mep") {
                  mejs.players[$(this).attr('id')].media.play();
              } else if (typecheck == "mep") {
                  mejs.players[$(this).attr('id')].media.pause();
              }
          });
      });
  });
```

Only issue I have with this code is that it *does* restart a video clip on scroll even if paused by the user.  Wasn't a deal-breaking issue on my site.  Here is the code in action:  [Ultrasoundoftheweek.com](http://ultrasoundoftheweek.com)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I managed to play a video only when the user scrolls to it.
I used IsInViewport plugin.
Hope you find it useful!

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    var video = $('.yourvideo');

    $(video).each(function(){

        if(video.is(':in-viewport')){

            video[0].play();

            video.removeClass('yourvideo');
            //I removed class to stop repeating the action ".play()" when it is scrolled again.
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a simple solution **without any dependencies**, here it is:

```
 let video = document.getElementById('video')

 function playVideoOnScroll () {
    const threshold = 300 //px above the video to start playing
    let offset = video.getBoundingClientRect().top
    if (offset < threshold) {
      demoVideo.play()
    } else {
      demoVideo.pause()
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('scroll', playVideoOnScroll, false)
  window.addEventListener('resize', playVideoOnScroll, false)
```

Answer (score 1):

My working solution in vanilla **2023** Javascript using **IntersectionObserver**:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                entry.target.play();
            } else {
                entry.target.pause();
            }
        });
    });
    videos.forEach(video => {
        observer.observe(video);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works, but introduces unnecessary complexity. The solution can be achieved with jQuery alone; there is no plugin needed to achieve the same results.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  const viewportBottom = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight;

  $('video').each(function () {
    if ($(this).offset().top + $(this).height() < window.scrollY) {
      $(this)[0].pause();
    } else if ($(this).offset().top < viewportBottom) {
      $(this)[0].play();
    }
  });
});
```