# Pause/play video when video is in the center of the viewport JWPlayer

Tags: jquery, scroll, viewport, jwplayer, playback

I am trying to Pause/play different videos once each reach the centre of the viewport, then pause them once you scroll away from them.

I am using JWPlayer but I am having issues pausing all the other videos on the page and keeping the current one playing that visible in the viewport.

https://jsfiddle.net/vv7jbrv6/1/

```
function onScrollVideo() {
   updateVideo();
}

function updateVideo() {

  var windowHeight = $(window).height(),

  gridTop = 200,
  gridBottom = 1000;

  $('.jwplayer').each(function() {
    var thisTop = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop(),
    playerID = $(this).prop('id');

    if (thisTop > gridTop && (thisTop + $(this).height()) < gridBottom) {
     jwplayer(playerID).play();

    } else {
     jwplayer(playerID).on('pause');

    }

  });

}
window.addEventListener('scroll', onScrollVideo, false);
```

Comment: have you tried `jwplayer(playerID).pause(true)`?

Comment: Here's my similar question discussing various ways to play html5 video when in viewport... but I think your problem is with the jwplayer API.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163756/html5-and-javascript-to-play-videos-only-when-visible/40011508#40011508

Answer (score 1):

```
  jwplayer(playerID).pause(true);
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vv7jbrv6/2/)

Comment: any success here?

Comment: They dont seem to start playing again once you scroll back up to them https://jsfiddle.net/vv7jbrv6/4/

Comment: looks like you're never getting into your `$('.jwplayer').each(function() {` loop.